# Map.get(assigns, :key) returns nil instead of expected value in the view

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In the template:

```
<%= @key %>
```

Template renders the value of `@key`, everything is fine here.

I want to use `@key` in the corresponding *view*, however

```
Map.get(conn.assigns, :key)
```

gives me `nil`. According to the documentation

> `@` is actually a macro that translates `@key` to `Map.get(assigns, :key)`

**So why above returns `nil` not the expected value?**

To confuse me even more, when I type

```
conn.assigns.key
```

in the *view*, it gives me the desired value.

Answer (score 5):

In templates `@conn.assigns` and `assigns` are two different things. `assigns` map comes from EEx and is what enables the `@var` syntax. `conn.assigns` comes from plug and is a common storage space for data that is needed in different plugs.
When you call `Phoenix.Controller.render/3` the assigns you pass there explicitly (as last argument) are merged with `conn.assigns` and that's passed to the template as `assigns`, but `conn.assigns` is not updated with new values.